# Kubernetes deploy tomcat probleme about liveness and readiness

Tags: kubernetes

I try to deploy my tomcat on kubernetes but when I run : `kubectl create -f deploy-tomcat.yaml` I have always the same error :

```
error from server (need to declare liveness (found 0), need to declare readiness (found 0)
```

deploy-tomcat.yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a liveness and readinessProbe to your manifest (on `containers` level), e.g.:

```
  readinessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: 8080
  livenessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: 8080
```

**Please note**, that this is not K8s default behavior to enforce the existence of those probes. I assume it was added to your K8s cluster with a [validating admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook).